# Calabash - android - NoMethodError in app_installation_hooks.rb

Tags: xamarin, calabash-android

I am having issues running calabash tests in xamarin cloud. The same tests work flawlessly on local devices. Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError - private method `test_server_path' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
./features/android/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:18:in `Before'
```

It's an error in calabash ruby framework, and since I can't replicate it locally, I'm clueless as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I used to launch 'test-cloud' command with multiple profiles as follow:

```
test-cloud [various options] --config config/cucumber.yml -p android -p another-profile
```

Multi profiles does work for 'calabash-android' cli (which is cucumber behind the scene) but not for 'test-cloud' command for which only one profile gets picked up. The solution is to add a profile in cucumber.yml that combines all the profiles you want to run in the cloud. This way you invoke the 'test-cloud' command with just one profile.